# Navigating to separate page instead of ui-view using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I use `ui-router` in AngularJS for navigation and I want to navigate to a new separate page instead of locating the content in the same page using `<div ui-view></div>`.